# disable add fields option while editing contacts in iphone

Tags: iphone, addressbook, abaddressbook

I have a query regarding AddressBookUI

ABPersonViewController *personController=[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
    //ABRecordRef aRecord=ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, 25);

```
personController.displayedPerson=ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, uniqueID);
personController.addressBook=addressBook;

personController.personViewDelegate=self;
personController.allowsEditing=YES;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
[personController release];
```

to show cotacts corresponding to a uniqueID

but when the view appears and I press the edit button

add fields option Appear, I want to hide this option.

Can this be done?????
If yes kindly suggest me some work around.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the standard Edit Contact view works.
You could write your own view&controller that reads the contacts values, puts them in input fields, and after the user has edited them, saves the contact. But that is quite a lot of work, and I would recomment that you use the standard View anyway.

In my opinion, it is better to use standard GUI elements as much as possible.